# Adding a link/UIbutton at the end of two lines of text in Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uilabel

I have a long string of text which might fit to 1 or many lines.
What I need to do is to show the first two lines and if the text is longer than that - add a "more" button/link that will point to another page/view controller that will show the full text.

I was thinking of adding a `UILabel`, calculate the text size and if it is too big - add a UIButton that will point to the next controller.

The problem is that:
1. With word wrapping, the last word in the line might end at the end of a line or at middle of line - I won't know where to put the "more" `UIButton`.
2. The text might be LTR and RTL so I don't know where to put the "more" button (on the left or the right).

Is there a way to link from a `UILabel`?
Should I use something other than `UILabel + UIButton`?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Example for LTR:**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur   adipiscing elit. Nulla
>   facilisis... -MORE-

**Example for RTL:**

> אם עוד אחרים בגרסה. תנך יכול פולנית או   , הארץ העברית על אנא, החלל
>   ...-MORE-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use a webview. HTML to load should be:

```
Your short text here...<a href="moreurl">-MORE-</a>
```

And adopt this method in UIWebviewDelegate

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
      NSURL *url = [request URL];
      if([[url absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"moreurl"])
     {
        //change html string to full string (without more)
        [webView loadHTMLString:@"Your full text here." baseURL:nil];
     }
      return YES;   
}
```

Hope that help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel). It has a very useful property for that called `attributedTruncationToken`.